# Need help cleaning up my XML parser code

Tags: c#, xml

So, I'm trying to familiarize myself with XML. To do this I have created a simple XML file and after that I created a C# script to read that XML file. Now everything works as intended but the code feel rather bad.

My XML looks like this:

```
<buildings>
    <building>
        <name>House</name>
        <buildTime>5</buildTime>
        <treeCost>100</treeCost>
        <stoneCost>10</stoneCost>
        <goldCost>10</goldCost>
    </building>

    <building>
        <name>Tower</name>
        <buildTime>5</buildTime>
        <treeCost>10</treeCost>
        <stoneCost>300</stoneCost>
        <goldCost>50</goldCost>
    </building>
</buildings>
```

And my C# code looks like this:

```
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load ("BuildingGame_Data/Buildings.xml");

    var names = xmlDoc.Descendants("building").Descendants("name");
    var buildTimes = xmlDoc.Descendants("building").Descendants("buildTime");
    var treeCosts = xmlDoc.Descendants("building").Descendants("treeCost");
    var stoneCosts = xmlDoc.Descendants("building").Descendants("stoneCost");
    var goldCosts = xmlDoc.Descendants("building").Descendants("goldCost");

    List<string> namesList = new List<string>();
    List<int> buildTimesList = new List<int>();
    List<int> treeCostsList = new List<int>();
    List<int> stoneCostsList = new List<int>();
    List<int> goldCostsList = new List<int>();

    foreach (string n in names)
    {
        namesList.Add(n);
    }

    foreach (string b in buildTimes)
    {
        buildTimesList.Add(System.Convert.ToInt32(b));
    }

    foreach (string t in treeCosts)
    {
        treeCostsList.Add(System.Convert.ToInt32(t));
    }

    foreach (string s in stoneCosts)
    {
        stoneCostsList.Add(System.Convert.ToInt32(s));
    }

    foreach (string g in goldCosts)
    {
        goldCostsList.Add(System.Convert.ToInt32(g));
    }


    List<Building> buildings = new List<Building>();
    for (int i = 0; i < namesList.Count; i++)
    {
        buildings.Add(new Building(namesList[i], buildTimesList[i], treeCostsList[i], stoneCostsList[i], goldCostsList[i]));
    }
```

Now, I would like a way to skip the middle part where I convert all my XML data and store it in different lists. It just seems like an unneccesary step, but I wasn't able to get it to work any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your descendants just do a select to map the xml to your class.  You can use `Element` to get the child elements of the "building" and cast them to the correct value.

```
var buildings = xmlDoc.Descendants("building")
                      .Select(be => new Building (
                          (string)be.Element("name"),
                          (int)be.Element("buildTime"),
                          (int)be.Element("treeCost"),
                          (int)be.Element("stoneCost"),
                          (int)be.Element("goldCost")))
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: When I implement this I get an error saying "Type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for `Select' and no extension method `Select' of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @JesperEvertsson You need to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Thank you, now it works as intended. The only problem now is that I don't really understand the code. Do you have any advice where I can read up on the topic and understand what is happening?

Comment: @JesperEvertsson This book is a great reference on all things Linq: http://www.amazon.com/Pro-LINQ-Language-Integrated-Experts/dp/1430226536/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1412600093&sr=8-5&keywords=c%23+linq

Comment: Ok, I might check it out. Thanks again for your help