# Parsing XML file with LINQ getting wrong information

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Im trying to parse an XML file from my program and I'm basing my code off this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26215694/2870873).

However the XML I'm using now is a bit more complex where I need to fill several nested lists with classes. Here are my two classes

```
public class Picture
{
    private int mPicNumber;
    private int mPicDuration;
    private List<string> mToSay = new List<string>();

    public Picture(int picNumber, int picDuration, List<string> toSay){...}

}


public class Sequence
{
    string mName;
    int mNumber;
    List<Picture> mPictures = new List<Picture>();

    public Sequence(string name, int number, List<Picture> pictures){...}
}
```

The XML looks like this

```
<sequences>
<sequence>
    <name>Seq 2</name>
    <number>1</number>
        <picture>
            <number>1</number>
            <duration>5</duration>
            <rows>
                <text>text1</text>
                <text>text2</text>
                <text>text3</text>
            </rows>
        </picture>  
        <picture>
            <number>2</number>
            <duration>5</duration>
            <rows>
                <text>text1</text>
                <text>text2</text>
                <text>text3</text>
            </rows>
        </picture>
        <picture>
            <number>3</number>
            <duration>5</duration>
            <rows>
                <text>text1</text>
                <text>text2</text>
                <text>text3</text>
            </rows>
        </picture>
</sequence>
<sequence>
    <name>Seq 2</name>
    <number>1</number>
        <picture>
            <number>1</number>
            <duration>5</duration>
            <rows>
                <text>text1</text>
                <text>text2</text>
                <text>text3</text>
            </rows>
        </picture>  
        <picture>
            <number>2</number>
            <duration>5</duration>
            <rows>
                <text>text1</text>
                <text>text2</text>
                <text>text3</text>
            </rows>
        </picture>
        <picture>
            <number>3</number>
            <duration>5</duration>
            <rows>
                <text>text1</text>
                <text>text2</text>
                <text>text3</text>
            </rows>
        </picture>
</sequence>
</sequences>
```

Here is the code for parsing the XML

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("Sequences.xml");
List<Picture> pictures;
List<string> toSay;

mSequences = xmlDoc.Descendants("sequence").
  Select(be => new Sequence(
    (string)be.Element("name"),
    (int)be.Element("number"),
    pictures = xmlDoc.Descendants("picture").
      Select(bf => new Picture(
        (int)bf.Element("number"),
        (int)bf.Element("duration"),
        toSay = xmlDoc.Descendants("rows").
          Select(bg =>
            (String)bg.Element("text")).ToList())).ToList())).ToList();
```

After I run this I get a list with 2 Sequences (which is correct) and the name and number is correct. However Each sequence contain all 6 pictures from the XML file and those pictures doesn't contain anything from within the rows tag. I tried changing Descendants to Elements on the two inner lists but then I got 0 pictures in all sequences instead. I will admit I'm not very good at LINQ and this is very confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is here `pictures = xmlDoc.Descendants("picture").` & `toSay = xmlDoc.Descendants("rows").`. You are again querying the XML from the top rather you should be querying the already filtered data. You should use the instance variable `be` & `bf` respectively.

This will give you the expected output:-

```
var res = xdoc.Root.Elements("sequence")
              .Select(be => new Sequence(
                        (string)be.Element("name"),
                        (int)be.Element("number"),
               pictures = be.Elements("picture")
                            .Select(bf => new Picture(
                           (int)bf.Element("number"),
                           (int)bf.Element("duration"),
                            toSay = bf.Element("rows").Elements("text")
                               Select(bg =>
                                       (String)bg).ToList()))
                                   .ToList()))
                             .ToList();
```

Also, note how I have replaced `Descendants` with `Elements`. If you XML contains some inner node with same tag then you will get unexpected output.

Comment: It looked like this was working, but at a closer look I only get the first text tag in every rows tag

Comment: @JesperEvertsson - Yeah you are correct, didn't noticed that. See `bf` represents each `picture` and we have to go down till `text` node which is present inside `rows` so I have used `bf.Element("rows").Elements("text")`. Also note now we can simply fetch the text in `Select` clause.

Answer (score 1):

pictures = xmlDoc.Descendants("picture")

It looks like you get the Pics from the whole document xmlDoc.Decendants,
but instead you need to get it for each be object I think. I can`t check it right now but i guess be.Decentans should be okay?

Comment: Ok, this actually makes so much sense. Works like a charm!

Comment: Nvm, i looked like this was working, but at a closer look I only get the first text tag in every rows tag